# MULTER req.file or req.files ALWAYS returns undefined

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am trying to upload an image from a form using `multer`, but each time the `req.files` and `req.file.path` return `undefined` in my console log.

I also get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

Here's my form code:

```
<form action="/admin/home/add-category" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Category</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Title</label>
                                <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Category Title"> <br>

                                <label>Upload Image</label>
                                <input name="cat_image" class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/*" id="selImg"  onchange="showImage.call(this)">
                                <img src="#" id="imgPreview" style="display: none; height: 100px; width: 100px">

                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and my code for configuring multer:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: ((req, file, cb) => {
       cb(null, 'uploads/category_images/');
    }),
   filename: ((req, file, cb) => {
       cb(null, file.originalname);
   })
});

const fileFilters = (req, file, cb) => {
   if (file.mimeType === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimeType === 'image/jpg' || 
       file.mimeType === 'image/png') {
         cb(null, true);
   } else {
         //cb(new Error('Image must be .jpeg, .jpg or .png format'), false);
        cb(null, false);
   }
};

const uploads = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
       fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilters
});
```

and the code for uploading the image:

```
router.post('/add-category', uploads.single('cat_image'), (req, res) => {

console.log(req.files); // undefined
console.log(req.filename); // undefined

let title = req.body.title;
console.log('Category Title:\t' + title);
let slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
let catImage = req.file.path; // error here

console.log(catImage);

let category = new Category({
    title: title,
    slug: slug,
    image: catImage
});

category.save()
    .then(result => {
        if (result) {
            console.log('Saved Category:\t' + result);
            res.redirect('/admin/home');
        }
    })
    .catch(errors => {
        console.error('Error Saving Category:\t' + errors);
    });

 });
```

I have been trying the whole day to figure this out. Can anyone help me understand why it's not working to fix this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding the multer middleware to express? Can you provide the options for it?

Comment: Please check the question again, I have added my multer configuration there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `cloudinary service` to get rid of all the hassle, as they have an `sdk for node` already. I'm not promoting anything here, just hope nobody else faces this issue.